# Trying to get return data from a tableview back to the previous controller with identifying information about which button selected the data

Tags: swift

In my first view controller, I have two instances of a class.

```
let test = MFDScreenModel()
let testtwo = MFDScreenModel()
```

they have a method to change variables

```
test.setDataVars(title: "", DP: "")
```

there are two buttons linked to one IBaction

when either button is touched, a segue to a table view is called.

```
@IBAction func sendData(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print(sender.currentTitle as Any)

    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToSettings", sender: self)
```

The table view:

```
class GuageSettingsViewController: UIViewController{

    
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    var dataPointList = MenuInfo()
    
    
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        
    }
   
}

extension GuageSettingsViewController: UITableViewDelegate{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        
        //Need to return this data with the Identifying info from the previous segue
      
    
    }
}
extension GuageSettingsViewController: UITableViewDataSource{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dataPointList.menuList.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ReusableCell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = dataPointList.menuList[indexPath.row].title
        return cell
    }
    
}
```

I need the returned data from the table view in a way that it will only change the vars passed

```
test.setDataVars(title: "", DP: "")
```

on either instance based on which button is pressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `GuageSettingsViewController` create a callback closure.
I don't know which type `menuList` represents, replace `MenuList` with the actual type

```
var callback : ((MenuList) -> Void)?
```

In the first view controller override `prepare(for segue` and assign the callback

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    guard segue.identifier == "goToSettings" else { return }
    let destination = segue.destination as! GuageSettingsViewController
    destination.callback = { [unowned self] info in
        // do something with info
    }
}
```

In `GuageSettingsViewController`/ `didSelectRowAt` insert this line

```
callback?(dataPointList.menuList[indexPath.row])
```